# Problem with openai API integration importing CreateChatCompletionRequestMessage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, openai-api

`const [messages, setMessages] = useState<ChatCompletionRequestMessage[]>([]);`

```
Error: Cannot find name 'ChatCompletionRequestMessage'.
```

I'm a beginner at Web Development and I'm trying to learn by building applications through YouTube tutorials.
I've seen that openai has recently been upgraded from v3 to v4 but I couldn't really find a solution to this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
import { CreateChatCompletionRequestMessage } from "openai/resources/chat";
```

If there is a major update in packages, you should dive into the `node_modules/openai` and search for it

Comment: Latest: `import { ChatCompletionMessageParam } from "openai/resources/chat/completions";`

Answer (score 3):

use **ChatCompletionMessageParam** instead, **CreateChatCompletionRequestMessage**  is deprecated as of version 4.4.0 of ***openai***

```
import { ChatCompletionMessageParam } from "openai/resources/chat";
```

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState<ChatCompletionMessageParam[]>([]);
```

Comment: Do you know why they decided to name it Param?

Comment: It can be imported directly from resources now: `import {ChatCompletionMessageParam} from 'openai/resources'`

Answer (score 1):

Create your own

```
interface ChatCompletionRequestMessage {
  role: 'user' | 'assistant' | 'system';
  content: string;
  name?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import { ChatCompletionMessageParam } from "openai/resources/chat/completions";

const [messages, setMessages] = useState<ChatCompletionMessageParam[]>([]);

"openai": "^4.24.1",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).